# "value was not in a correct format" error when converting a string to an int32

Tags: c#, string, double, int32

this is my code;

```
string a="11.4";

int b,c;

b=2;

c= convert.toint32(a) * b
```

I get this error;

> Input string was not in a correct format

how can i convert "a"?

Comment: `a` is not valid int, it's a `double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `a` is just not an integer value - you could use `Convert.ToDouble()` instead. To guard against parsing errors in case that is a possibility use `double.TryParse()` instead:

```
string a = "11.4";
double d;

if (double.TryParse(a, out d))
{
    //d now contains the double value
}
```

**Edit:**

Taking the comments into account, of course it is always best to specify the culture settings. Here an example using culture-indepenent settings with `double.TryParse()` which would result in `11.4` as result:

```
if (double.TryParse(a, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
{
    //d now contains the double value
}
```

Comment: Side note: depending on culture settings 11.4 may actually parse OK as integer (if "." is group separator); it may as well fail to parse as double (if decimal separator is ","). It is good practice to specify culture when parsing values.

Comment: @BrokenGlass, what do you expect for `d`? `11.4` or `114.0`? Both are correct depending on the culture. Getting an exception `Input string was not in a correct format` is more safer than the wrong value

Answer (score 1):

A very first glance, the number literal "11.4" is not a actual "int". Try some other converting format, such as ToDouble()

I have tried following code in C# for your reference.

```
        string a = "11.4";
        double num_a = Convert.ToDouble(a);
        int b = 2;
        double ans = num_a * b;
```

Comment: And My VS2010 debugger says `ans=228.0`. Read Alexei Levenkov's comment

Comment: @L.B 228.0? it's weird. Have you tried to break down the code and step through to find out exactly what each variable's value?

Comment: Not weird. Just add this line before your code `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR");` or `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");`

Comment: @L.B Oh I got it after read Alexei's comment. Thank you for reminding! :)